# /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/cwchar:44:10: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory (Homebrew GCC compiler not working)

Tags: c++, gcc, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I have installed GCC compiler on my Mac through Homebrew using "brew install gcc" command. The installation was successful, but when I try to compile a simple C++ program I run into error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello Mac"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error Message

```
swithinabner@Johns-Air Bench % g++-10 Bench.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:38,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from Bench.cpp:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/cwchar:44:10: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
   44 | #include <wchar.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

WHAT I HAVE ALREADY TRIED

1. Compiling using an earlier version (gcc version -6.5.0) and I end up with the same error.
2. Compiling a C file using gcc-10 command -> It throws up similar kind
   of (No such file) error.
3. Updating Xcode Command line tools and Home brew.

I'm using a M1 MacBook Air 2020 which runs macOS Big Sur.

Comment: does it work without `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` ?

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: No, I tried without (#include<bits/stdc++.h>) and it doesn't work!